# how to solve webdriver manager exception: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in edge

Tags: robotframework, webdrivermanager-python

I am trying to implement webdriver-manager for an existing project in Robot Framework. I use the following webdriver manager python file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

def install_edgedriver():
    driver = webdriver.Edge(service=EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
    return driver
```

And I use the driver in this way:

```
***Settings***
Library    drivermanager.py

***Keywords***
Open Test Environment
    ${edgedriver}=    Install Edgedriver    
    Open Browser    {web page url}    edge    executable_path=${edgedriver}    alias=BrowserA
```

When I try to run the test, the browser opens, but the website cannot be loaded. I receive the following exception:

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
(Session info: MicrosoftEdge=114.0.1823.37)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF69030B572+64226]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF69029BB32+770962]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69005CC3C]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF690054CFA]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69004956F]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69004ABCF]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6900497DD]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF690048850]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6900487AC]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF690047033]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF690047796]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69005EC56]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6900D8B61]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6900BEFEA]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF690094BA1]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6900D7FB1]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6900BEDC3]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF690093BDC]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF690092DC6]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF690094354]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF6904E8E19+1319081]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69010BEE8]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6901E7AB1+33553]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6901DFEEF+1871]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF6904E7A33+1313987]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6902A4168+20232]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6902A0784+5412]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6902A087C+5660]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF690294531+740753]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB520B7614+20]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB523226A1+33]

What I should do differently?

Comment: value of `{web page url}` doesn't contain a hostname that your nameserver can resolve into IP address.  Fix that.